# Touch events double firing on Safari for iOS

Tags: android, ios, html, safari, touch

We have a webapp built using Bootstrap, Angular, and MongoDB that is run on NodeJS with express.  There is an image on one part of the site that responds to touch or mouse events on that image.  There are javascript functions that are called each time a touch (or mouse click) begins and ends.  The code implementing this is:

```
            <div class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                <div class="col-xs-4 nopadding">
                    <p class="noheightgap">
                    <a class="img-responsive">
                        <img id="1" onmousedown="BeginClick(event);" onmouseup="EndClick(event);"
                             ontouchstart="BeginTouch(event);" ontouchend="EndTouch(event);" src="../public/img/Custom-1.png" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                    </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This code works as expected on all desktop browsers we have tested, as well as on the Android Chrome browser.  However, using Safari on an iPhone, or the Dolphin HD browser on Android, it seems that the ontouchstart and ontouchend methods are both fired twice by some touches. (Touches that last longer)  We never see more than two sets of these events fired.  In all cases, we are using

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to prevent rogue events from firing.  Is there something that could be causing the touch events to be fired multiple times on Safari on the iPhone and Dolphin on Android?

Comment: Whenever I run into this issue in jQuery, I am always sure to unbind current event handlers before re-binding the behavior I really want. I realize preventDefault() sort of does that -- the question is does it clear *all* bound event-handlers?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, we can't do that because we need that image along with other images waiting for touches on the page to remain listening for more touches once the current touch is complete.  So I do not think we can unbind the touch handler, only use preventDefault() to stop the current touch's event stack once we have finished using it?